# How to input 3 sides of a triangle and then decide if it is a right triangle

Tags: java

This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Right_Triangle
{   
    public static void main (String args [])
    {

        String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("What is the length of your hypotenuse?");
        String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("What is the length of your base?");
        String z = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("What is the height of your triangle?");
        double a = Double.parseDouble(x);

        a = Math.pow (x,2);
        b = Math.pow (y,2);
        c = Math.pow (z,2);
        if (a + b == c)
        {
            System.out.println ("Right triangle");
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this not compile?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add a question. While you add this, also review your formatting. (Add.) Also review your Title -- it's useless.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Comment: Watch out for rounding errors. Your code will produce wrong results in some cases due to rounding.

Comment: Your question should have been about, "Why an I getting this result?" or "What is wrong with my formatting to make it look like this?" Your title should be a direct version of the question. Then in the description state that you are a noob, if you wish. Then describe your results. Then the confusion or frustration that you have about them, following your results. Then conclude with your code. Do this and you will receive help, do it not and you will be down-voted. You can go back and edit this question though. The edit button is right under your code snippet. Please do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing one of your inputs to create a double:

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(x);
```

but you also need to do this for the other two inputs (y and z)

Also, you need to do the calculations using the parsed doubles (a,b,c), not the original Strings (x,y,z).

See also SpiderPig's comment about rounding errors. If your triangles have integer side lengths, then you should represent them as integers, not doubles - and square the side lengths using `x*x` not `math.pow(x,2)`